# How to pass data from input to a custom service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJS and I have a problem: how to display the hex equivalent of the number inserted into the input box?

I am using `ng-change` to see if the input is modified and the output should also change according to the input.

This is the code:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="in" ng-change="hex(in)"> 
  {{in}} <br>{{hex}}
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
      return x.toString(16);
    }
  });
    
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.in= 11;
    $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc($scope.in);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Praveen It is simply not working. It works for the first time when the page is loaded but then if i change the input the chrome inspector says this:   TypeError: v2.hex is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y4cgpxvGSqB1HtMyIXJx?p=preview). Problem is that you are using function name as assignment.

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="in" ng-change="convertToHex(in)"> 
 $scope.convertToHex= function(value) {
       $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it does not work?

In your input, you try to call a function:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="in" ng-change="hex(in)">
```

But `$scope.hex` is **not** a function in your controller:

```
$scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc($scope.in);
```

---

#### How to fix it?

Change it to:

```
$scope.hex = function() {
    $scope.result = hexafy.myFunc($scope.in);
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.in= 11;
    $scope.hex = function() {
        $scope.result = hexafy.myFunc($scope.in);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="in" ng-change="hex()"> 
    {{in}} <br>{{result}}
</div>
```

Comment: function hex is passing the value. I thing you missed to update in controller

Comment: @PraveenMP Not necessary. The method may work without parameter (as it always pass the same `$scope.in` variable).